# Youtube API Query; exclude one video from feed?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Is there a  way to exclude one video from a Youtube API Feed?

I already tried using the `?q=` query (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#qsp), but you first need to find videos with a certain keyword, before you can exclude videos... I just want to exclude 1 video, preferably by it's videoID;

```
<script src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/USERID/uploads?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showMyVideos2&amp;max-results=3&amp;format=5&amp;q=keyword1+-keyword2"></script>
```

(btw the `q=` query is at the end)

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much easier just to exclude that item when executing your `showMyVideos2()` callback function. In general, query parameters are better suited for matching/excluding based on metadata than on video id.